# CKEditor Custom button html comment indicator?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have created a custom button in CKEditor v4 which inserts an html comment `<!--more-->`
in the editor in order to break the article showing a read more link when the page is rendered.

The problem that due to being an html comment the "more" element doesn't show in the editor unless the user switches to Html source (by pressing the Html source button).

Is there any way i can render a visual indicator to show that the 'more' button has been pressed in the normal view of the editor (a border-line or something)? This is common in Wordpress's editor ( which is a tinymce editor but nonetheless).
Any ideas will do, thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a CKEditor integration for Wordpress and I think that it already includes such plugin.

Comment: Sorry i should have mentioned. I'm not using wordpress, i'm developing with Asp.net Mvc. I referred wordpress as merely an example for what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Anyway, you can look at that integration for the plugin and use it.